# Verify if a row exists sqlite

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I'm new in sqlite and I have a problem. I'm programming in Lua.

I've a sqlite database with a table called "`prova`". This table has a column called "`ultimotime`" that can be 0 or 1. I want to set all the "`ultimotime`" values to 0 if the "`ultimotime`" of all the table's rows are 1.

Sorry for my English and thanks everybody

Comment: So, to confirm: boolean column `ultimotime` of `prova`; if _no_ rows are `0`, set _all_ rows to `0`. Otherwise do nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"All rows are 1" is the same as "*no* rows are 0".
The latter can be easily checked with NOT EXISTS:

```sql
UPDATE prova
SET ultimotime = 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM prova
                  WHERE ultimotime = 0)
```

Comment: @Nick21Android: Please mark the answer as approved, if it satisfies your needs.....